# How to create dynamic filters in my R Shiny App to automatically update the values in 2nd filter based on the selection of value in the 1st filter

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create dynamic filters in my R Shiny App to automatically update the values in 2nd filter based on the selection of value in the 1st filter. I tried to make changes to my code but it is not working. I am not able to undestand where to make changes to me code. Any help much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Code below:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage, theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                           
                      
     sidebarLayout(position="left",
             sidebarPanel( width = 3,
                                                         
                 selectizeInput("group", "group",
                                choices = rug$group, selected="NONE", multiple = TRUE),
                 selectizeInput("name", "name",
                                choices = rug$name, selected="NONE", multiple = TRUE),
                 selectizeInput("dosis", "Dosis",
                                choices = rug$dosis, selected="NONE", multiple = TRUE),
                 selectizeInput("schema", "schema",
                               choices = rug$schema,  selected = character(0), multiple = TRUE, options = list(maxItems = 6)),
                            submitButton("Choose"),
                            
                                                         
                                           ),
           mainPanel(
              tabsetPanel(
                
               tabPanel("schema",  tags$label(h3('schema')), dataTableOutput("rug_data"),
                        
         
                                             )))))
        
)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$rug_data <- renderDataTable({
  
    
    rug_filter <- subset(rug, rownames=FALSE, 
                          rug$group == input$group & 
                            rug$name == input$name &
                            rug$dosis == input$dosis &
                            rug$schema == input$schema  ) 
    
  })
```

***Edited Code***

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram

shinyServer(function(session, input, output) {
  

observeEvent(input$group,{
  updateSelectInput(
    session,
    "name",
    choices = rug %>%
      filter(group== input$group) %>%
      select(name) %>%
      unique() %>%
      pull(name)
  )
  
})
  
               
              
observeEvent({
  updateSelectInput(
    session, "group"
    choices = rug %>%
      select(group) %>%
      unique() %>%
      pull(group) 
  )
})

observeEvent({
  updateSelectInput(
    session, "dosis",
    choices = rug %>%
      select(dosis) %>%
      unique() %>%
      pull(dosis)
  )
})

observeEvent({
  updateSelectInput(
    session, "schema",
    choices = rug %>%
      select(schema) %>%
      unique() %>%
      pull(schema)
  )
})


output$rug_data <- renderTable({
    rug, rownames=FALSE
    
 })
})
```

***Data***

```
dput(head(rug,500))
structure(list(group = c("Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", 
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi"), name = c("Bup", 
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", 
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", 
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", 
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", 
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", 
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", 
"Bup", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", 
"Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Hydro", 
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", 
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", 
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", 
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", 
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", 
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", 
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", 
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Fent", 
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", 
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", 
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", 
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", 
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", 
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", 
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Hyd", 
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", 
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", 
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", 
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", 
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", 
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", 
"Hyd", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", 
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", 
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", 
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", 
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", 
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", 
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", 
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", 
"Morp", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", 
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", 
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", 
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", 
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", 
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", 
"Oxyc", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", 
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", 
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", 
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", 
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", 
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", 
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", 
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", 
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", 
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", 
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", 
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", 
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", 
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", 
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", 
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", 
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", 
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", 
"Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", 
"Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", 
"Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", 
"Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram"
), dosis = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 120, 120, 120, 
120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 
180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 
400, 400, 400, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 
64, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 200, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
80, 80, 80, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 
12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 75, 75, 
75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
150, 150, 150, 150), schema = c("LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", 
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", 
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", 
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", 
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", 
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", 
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", 
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", 
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", 
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", 
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", 
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", 
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", 
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", 
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", 
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", 
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", 
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", 
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", 
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", 
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", 
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", 
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", 
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", 
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", 
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", 
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", 
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", 
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", 
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10"
), Week = c("Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", 
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", 
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2"), Weekly_up = c(2.4375, 
2.38, 2.25, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.875, 1.25, 4.875, 4.75, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 
3.75, 2.5, 9.75, 9.5, 9, 8, 8, 6, 7.5, 5, 14.625, 14.25, 13.5, 
12, 12, 9, 11.25, 7.5, 19.5, 19, 18, 16, 16, 12, 15, 10, 29.25, 
28.5, 27, 24, 24, 18, 22.5, 15, 39, 38, 36, 32, 32, 24, 30, 20, 
24.375, 23.75, 22.5, 20, 20, 15, 18.75, 12.5, 48.75, 47.5, 45, 
40, 40, 30, 37.5, 25, 29.25, 28.5, 27, 24, 24, 18, 22.5, 15, 
43.875, 42.75, 40.5, 36, 36, 27, 33.75, 22.5, 58.5, 57, 54, 48, 
48, 36, 45, 30, 87.75, 85.5, 81, 72, 72, 54, 67.5, 45, 117, 114, 
108, 96, 96, 72, 90, 60, 131.625, 128.25, 121.5, 108, 108, 81, 
101.25, 67.5, 175.5, 171, 162, 144, 144, 108, 135, 90, 48.75, 
47.5, 45, 40, 40, 30, 37.5, 25, 97.5, 95, 90, 80, 80, 60, 75, 
50, 146.25, 142.5, 135, 120, 120, 90, 112.5, 75, 195, 190, 180, 
160, 160, 120, 150, 100, 292.5, 285, 270, 240, 240, 180, 225, 
150, 390, 380, 360, 320, 320, 240, 300, 200, 585, 570, 540, 480, 
480, 360, 450, 300, 1.95, 1.9, 1.8, 1.6, 1.6, 1.2, 1.5, 1, 3.9, 
3.8, 3.6, 3.2, 3.2, 2.4, 3, 2, 7.8, 7.6, 7.2, 6.4, 6.4, 4.8, 
6, 4, 15.6, 15.2, 14.4, 12.8, 12.8, 9.6, 12, 8, 23.4, 22.8, 21.6, 
19.2, 19.2, 14.4, 18, 12, 31.2, 30.4, 28.8, 25.6, 25.6, 19.2, 
24, 16, 62.4, 60.8, 57.6, 51.2, 51.2, 38.4, 48, 32, 4.875, 4.75, 
4.5, 4, 4, 3, 3.75, 2.5, 9.75, 9.5, 9, 8, 8, 6, 7.5, 5, 14.625, 
14.25, 13.5, 12, 12, 9, 11.25, 7.5, 29.25, 28.5, 27, 24, 24, 
18, 22.5, 15, 48.75, 47.5, 45, 40, 40, 30, 37.5, 25, 58.5, 57, 
54, 48, 48, 36, 45, 30, 97.5, 95, 90, 80, 80, 60, 75, 50, 195, 
190, 180, 160, 160, 120, 150, 100, 2.4375, 2.38, 2.25, 2, 2, 
1.5, 1.875, 1.25, 4.875, 4.75, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 3.75, 2.5, 9.75, 
9.5, 9, 8, 8, 6, 7.5, 5, 19.5, 19, 18, 16, 16, 12, 15, 10, 39, 
38, 36, 32, 32, 24, 30, 20, 78, 76, 72, 64, 64, 48, 60, 40, 2.4375, 
2.38, 2.25, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.875, 1.25, 4.875, 4.75, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 
3.75, 2.5, 9.75, 9.5, 9, 8, 8, 6, 7.5, 5, 14.625, 14.25, 13.5, 
12, 12, 9, 11.25, 7.5, 19.5, 19, 18, 16, 16, 12, 15, 10, 29.25, 
28.5, 27, 24, 24, 18, 22.5, 15, 39, 38, 36, 32, 32, 24, 30, 20, 
12.1875, 11.88, 11.25, 10, 10, 7.5, 9.375, 6.25, 24.375, 23.75, 
22.5, 20, 20, 15, 18.75, 12.5, 48.75, 47.5, 45, 40, 40, 30, 37.5, 
25, 73.125, 71.25, 67.5, 60, 60, 45, 56.25, 37.5, 97.5, 95, 90, 
80, 80, 60, 75, 50, 146.25, 142.5, 135, 120, 120, 90, 112.5, 
75, 195, 190, 180, 160, 160, 120, 150, 100, 24.375, 23.75, 22.5, 
20, 20, 15, 18.75, 12.5, 48.75, 47.5, 45, 40, 40, 30, 37.5, 25, 
73.125, 71.25, 67.5, 60, 60, 45, 56.25, 37.5, 97.5, 95, 90, 80, 
80, 60, 75, 50, 146.25, 142.5, 135, 120)), row.names = c(NA, 
-500L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing filtered unique values back to a Shiny dropdown box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73894197/passing-filtered-unique-values-back-to-a-shiny-dropdown-box)

Comment: Hi, this looks perfect! but I have total 4 filters in my data, whereas in this solution there are only 2 filters, I am not sure where to add the unique values for other filters. Could you please help?

Comment: The principle is easy to extend.  Simply observe the change in the relevant parent input and the update the child input.  There's no need to update grandcildren manually: Shiny's reacyivity will cascade the changes automatically.  We can't provide a conrete solution that is directly applicable as you haven't made your code reproducible.

Comment: Thank you for encouraging!! I tried some modifications but I get an error as ``` Error in is_quosure(expr) : argument "expr" is missing, with no default ```

Comment: Is `rug` reactive or static? You use both `rug` and `rug()`. If it’s reactive, `rug` is incorrect. If it’s static, `rug()` is incorrect.  And you’ve given us a `dput` of `Rug_data` (thank you), but not `rug`? How are the two related. Help yourself by helping us to help you. Make sure your question is both minimal and reproducible. At the moment, it is neither.

Comment: sorry my bad, I was trying to create dummy data, happend during the procces of creating. actually its rug, I have updated it as ```rug``` also in the code. Now I don't get any error but the filters are not working as I wanted. Somehow the link is broken between the filters. Scratching head..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [selectizeGroup-module](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/selectizeGroup-module.html) from library([shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets)).

It creates a

> Group of mutually dependent `selectizeInput` for filtering
> data.frame's columns (like in Excel).

Please check the following:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

rug <- structure(list(group = c("Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi",
"Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi", "Opi"), name =
c("Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup",
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup",
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup",
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup",
"Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup", "Bup",
"Bup", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod",
"Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Cod", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro",
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro",
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro",
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro",
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro",
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro",
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro",
"Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Hydro", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent",
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent",
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent",
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent",
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent",
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent",
"Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Fent", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd",
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd",
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd",
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd",
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd",
"Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Hyd", "Morp", "Morp",
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp",
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp",
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp",
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp",
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp",
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp",
"Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Morp", "Oxyc",
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc",
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc",
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc",
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc",
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc", "Oxyc",
"Oxyc", "Oxyc", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo",
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo",
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo",
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo",
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo",
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo",
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo",
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo",
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo",
"OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "OxycNalo", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen",
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen",
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen",
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen",
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen",
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen",
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen",
"Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tapen", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram",
"Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram",
"Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram",
"Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram",
"Tram", "Tram", "Tram", "Tram" ), dosis = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
2.5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15,
15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30,
30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50,
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45,
45, 45, 45, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90,
120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135, 135,
135, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150,
150, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300,
300, 300, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 600, 600, 600, 600, 600,
600, 600, 600, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
8, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 32,
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 30, 30,
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60,
60, 60, 60, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200,
200, 200, 200, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 40, 40, 40,
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5,
2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15,
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30,
30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5,
12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50,
50, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200,
200, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 75, 75,
75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 150, 150, 150,
150), schema = c("LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20",
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20",
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10",
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25",
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25",
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20",
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20",
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10",
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25",
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25",
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20",
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20",
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10",
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25",
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25",
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20",
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20",
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10",
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25",
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25",
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20",
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20",
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10",
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25",
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25",
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20",
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20",
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10",
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25",
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25",
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20",
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20",
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10",
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25",
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25",
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20",
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20",
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10",
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25",
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25",
"SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20",
"SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20",
"SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10", "LAB_10",
"SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25", "LAB_10",
"LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_20", "SAB_20", "SAB_25", "SAB_25",
"LAB_10", "LAB_10", "SAB_10", "SAB_10" ), Week = c("Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2",
"Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1", "Woche2", "Woche1",
"Woche2"), Weekly_up = c(2.4375, 2.38, 2.25, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.875, 1.25, 4.875,
4.75, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 3.75, 2.5, 9.75, 9.5, 9, 8, 8, 6, 7.5, 5, 14.625, 14.25,
13.5, 12, 12, 9, 11.25, 7.5, 19.5, 19, 18, 16, 16, 12, 15, 10, 29.25, 28.5,
27, 24, 24, 18, 22.5, 15, 39, 38, 36, 32, 32, 24, 30, 20, 24.375, 23.75, 22.5,
20, 20, 15, 18.75, 12.5, 48.75, 47.5, 45, 40, 40, 30, 37.5, 25, 29.25, 28.5,
27, 24, 24, 18, 22.5, 15, 43.875, 42.75, 40.5, 36, 36, 27, 33.75, 22.5, 58.5,
57, 54, 48, 48, 36, 45, 30, 87.75, 85.5, 81, 72, 72, 54, 67.5, 45, 117, 114,
108, 96, 96, 72, 90, 60, 131.625, 128.25, 121.5, 108, 108, 81, 101.25, 67.5,
175.5, 171, 162, 144, 144, 108, 135, 90, 48.75, 47.5, 45, 40, 40, 30, 37.5,
25, 97.5, 95, 90, 80, 80, 60, 75, 50, 146.25, 142.5, 135, 120, 120, 90, 112.5,
75, 195, 190, 180, 160, 160, 120, 150, 100, 292.5, 285, 270, 240, 240, 180,
225, 150, 390, 380, 360, 320, 320, 240, 300, 200, 585, 570, 540, 480, 480,
360, 450, 300, 1.95, 1.9, 1.8, 1.6, 1.6, 1.2, 1.5, 1, 3.9, 3.8, 3.6, 3.2, 3.2,
2.4, 3, 2, 7.8, 7.6, 7.2, 6.4, 6.4, 4.8, 6, 4, 15.6, 15.2, 14.4, 12.8, 12.8,
9.6, 12, 8, 23.4, 22.8, 21.6, 19.2, 19.2, 14.4, 18, 12, 31.2, 30.4, 28.8,
25.6, 25.6, 19.2, 24, 16, 62.4, 60.8, 57.6, 51.2, 51.2, 38.4, 48, 32, 4.875,
4.75, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 3.75, 2.5, 9.75, 9.5, 9, 8, 8, 6, 7.5, 5, 14.625, 14.25,
13.5, 12, 12, 9, 11.25, 7.5, 29.25, 28.5, 27, 24, 24, 18, 22.5, 15, 48.75,
47.5, 45, 40, 40, 30, 37.5, 25, 58.5, 57, 54, 48, 48, 36, 45, 30, 97.5, 95,
90, 80, 80, 60, 75, 50, 195, 190, 180, 160, 160, 120, 150, 100, 2.4375, 2.38,
2.25, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.875, 1.25, 4.875, 4.75, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 3.75, 2.5, 9.75, 9.5,
9, 8, 8, 6, 7.5, 5, 19.5, 19, 18, 16, 16, 12, 15, 10, 39, 38, 36, 32, 32, 24,
30, 20, 78, 76, 72, 64, 64, 48, 60, 40, 2.4375, 2.38, 2.25, 2, 2, 1.5, 1.875,
1.25, 4.875, 4.75, 4.5, 4, 4, 3, 3.75, 2.5, 9.75, 9.5, 9, 8, 8, 6, 7.5, 5,
14.625, 14.25, 13.5, 12, 12, 9, 11.25, 7.5, 19.5, 19, 18, 16, 16, 12, 15, 10,
29.25, 28.5, 27, 24, 24, 18, 22.5, 15, 39, 38, 36, 32, 32, 24, 30, 20,
12.1875, 11.88, 11.25, 10, 10, 7.5, 9.375, 6.25, 24.375, 23.75, 22.5, 20, 20,
15, 18.75, 12.5, 48.75, 47.5, 45, 40, 40, 30, 37.5, 25, 73.125, 71.25, 67.5,
60, 60, 45, 56.25, 37.5, 97.5, 95, 90, 80, 80, 60, 75, 50, 146.25, 142.5, 135,
120, 120, 90, 112.5, 75, 195, 190, 180, 160, 160, 120, 150, 100, 24.375,
23.75, 22.5, 20, 20, 15, 18.75, 12.5, 48.75, 47.5, 45, 40, 40, 30, 37.5, 25,
73.125, 71.25, 67.5, 60, 60, 45, 56.25, 37.5, 97.5, 95, 90, 80, 80, 60, 75,
50, 146.25, 142.5, 135, 120)), row.names = c(NA, -500L), class = c("tbl_rug",
"tbl", "data.frame"))


    ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 10, offset = 1, tags$h3("Filter data with selectize group")),
    column(width = 3, offset = 1, 
           selectizeGroupUI(
             id = "my-filters",
             params = list(
               group = list(inputId = "group", title = "group:"),
               name = list(inputId = "name", title = "name:"),
               dosis = list(inputId = "dosis", title = "dosis:"),
               schema = list(inputId = "schema", title = "schema:")
             ),
             inline = FALSE
           )),
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filtered_table <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters",
    data = rug,
    vars = names(rug),
    inline = FALSE
  )
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    hide_columns <- which(names(filtered_table()) %in% c("dosis", "schema"))
    datatable(filtered_table(), options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = hide_columns))), rownames = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you! One last question, can I please also know how to modify the code to drop few columns in the output rendered table?

Comment: @KApril This can be done via `datatable`'s `option` argument. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, it works perfect! I have already accepted your answer

Comment: hello I have added rownames=False to hid the index of the table ```datatable(filtered_table(), rownames=FALSE, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = hide_columns))))``` but it doesn't work. I am not able to understand why.

Comment: @KApril works fine for me - please check my edit.

Comment: somehow my table is not displaying after I have added rownames to the code as you have mentioned.